# dmidecode will read a Dell service tag - how can it be changed?

Tags: dell, laptop, firmware, dmidecode

After replacing the motherboard in a Dell laptop due to physical damage, it has the "Other" service tag. The system technically is under regular warranty, but not with this "Other" service tag. Is there a way to change it to match the System?

The `dmidecode` command will read a Dell service tag, but how can it be changed?

Comment: I'm sure Dell knows the original service tag and the replacement service tag. You can contact them if you are worried about warranty.

Answer (score 0):

There is a program `dellbiosreset.iso` that may do what you seek:

- [Utility to change a service tag listed in the BIOS?](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Utility-to-change-a-service-tag-listed-in-the-BIOS/td-p/4121688)

**Warning:** Thread contains drama.